# Conditional class not always triggers on Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have the following snippet which works fine on Chrome, Edge, but no so well on some versions of IE 11 and Firefox.

On some versions of IE 11, not always the class gets set, and on Firefox it has some delay.

Any ideas how to do this better?

**// TS**

```
this.scrollYSub = Observable.fromEvent(window, 'scroll')
    .throttleTime(5)
    .subscribe(e => {
        this.scrollY = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
});
```

**// HTML**

```
<nav id="nav" [class.fixednav]="scrollY >= 245">
```

**/* CSS */**

```
.fixednav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 95px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the scroll event doesn't run inside Angulars zone in all browsers because of limitations of the polyfills.

```ts
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef /* or private zone:NgZone */) {}

this.scrollYSub = Observable.fromEvent(window, 'scroll')
    .throttleTime(5)
    .subscribe(e => {
        this.scrollY = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();

        // or
        /*
        this.zone.run(() {
          this.scrollY = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        });
        */
});
```

If the code only changes local properties of the current component, `this.cdRef.detectChanges();` is usually the better way.

If the code also calls methods that cause changes in other components or services the `zone.run(...)` approach is preferred because it runs change detection in the whole application, instead of only the current component.

An alternative way would be

```ts
scroll = new Subject();

@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
onScroll(event) {
  this.scroll.next(event);
}
```

because this way ensures the event handler is executed inside Angulars zone.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the CSS by default and hide the element. If the condition applies then show the element (or apply a class that will show it). Then you won't get any jumping around during page load.